# Hibernate Session High CPU Usage

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been trying to investigate my app as it is creating heavy cpu usage. I tried to analyze Heap Dump with MAT. In Leak Report i have found  below cause.

```
 One instance of "org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x6c5bd5258" occupies 1,091,121,328 (38.09%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$HashEntry[]" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x6c5bd5258".

Keywords
org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl
org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$HashEntry[]
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x6c5bd5258
```

Now, ehcache.xml

```
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="2000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="6000" timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
    overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
</defaultCache>

<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="21600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="21600" overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
</cache>

<!-- mandatory if you want to distribute the query cache -->
<cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="400000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
</cache>
```

Here, ehcache-distributed.xml

```
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="20000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="6000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
</defaultCache>

<cache  name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
    timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,replicatePuts=false,replicateUpdates=true,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false,replicateRemovals=true" />
</cache>

<!-- mandatory if you want to distribute the query cache -->
<cache  name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxElementsInMemory="400000"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    <!-- please note the mandatory replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true -->
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,replicatePuts=true,replicateUpdates=true,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,replicateRemovals=true" />
</cache>
```

Hibernate Version:

```
<hibernate.version>3.5.5-Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-validator.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
```

Can you guys help me understand these settings ? Is this best practice or is there any wrong configuration ?

Comment: So, you have a CPU usage problem, and to find where it comes from, you look at what the memory contains? I would understand if you had a memory usage problem. But having things in memory doesn't consume any CPU.

Comment: When i was trying to investigate, i have found that GC was causing heavy CPU usage. S0 and S1 shows zero and Old space becomes 100 percent within seconds.Causes almost every second a FGC.

So, isn't it related what i did ? @JBNizet